# Why the time taken by my program in MS Visual Studio 2013 in RELEASE mode in 64-bit mode is one-third of the time taken in 32-bit mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, hevc, h.265

I am running HM-16.15 encoder in RELEASE mode in Visual Studio 2013. HM-16.15 encoder is a very large C++ program (200k lines of code). I have two timings (T1 and T2). Total Time taken by program T = T1 + T2.

when I build and debug the program in 64-bit mode and 32-bit mode separately. The time taken in 64-bit mode in comparison to 32-bit are as follows

- T1(64bit) = T1(32bit) x 0.34     nearly
- T2(64bit) = T2(32bit) x 0.78     nearly

According to my knowledge T1(64bit) should be greater than or equal to T1(32bit) x 0.5. But how this happens for T1?

Comment: HM-16.15 encoder is the code for HEVC (High efficiency video coding) which encodes the raw video files in yuv format

Comment: Why do you think that this is always true: "T1(64bit) should be greater than or equal to T1(32bit) x 0.5"?

Comment: The 64-bit target is generally more comfortable with various things, such as 64-bit arithmetic and accessing large amounts of memory, but the difference is _much_ more subtle than a simple constant factor and can easily go in the opposite direction. I do not know this library but the explanation could be as simple as that the code has been optimized with the 64-bit target in mind, less little care or even unoptimized fallback functions being used in 32-bit builds. Conversely 64-bit software, especially pointer-heavy code, typically uses more memory and may easily end up blowing the cache.

Answer (score 2):

The **[x86_64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64)** (64-bit) platform is much more than twice the width of the **x86** (32-bit).

In addition to wider registers (64-bit instead of 32-bit), x86_64 has:

- 8 more general-purpose registers (r8, r9, r10, r11, r12, r13, r14, r15)
- 8 more streaming (SSE) registers
- Vector extensions (AVX)
- More instructions, e.g. instruction pointer relative data access
- The x86_64 [calling convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#x86-64_calling_conventions) uses more registers for argument passing and is faster than the 32-bit cdecl or even fastcall (Windows ABI)
- Some arithmetic on a x86_64 CPU may be faster in 64-bit mode than 32-bit mode (e.g. IMUL r64 is 3c vs. IMUL r32 is 4c)

It is thus not unusual to see T1(64bit) < T1(32bit) x 0.5, but it can also easily go the other way. In general it is hard to predict which way this relation is going to go without actually testing and profiling your code.

Comment: XMM is the name of SSE registers, so they are the same. And is it really the case that x86_64 has more SSE instructions? I'm not sure on this one.

Comment: @geza In case of x86(_64) 64bit versions tend to have more sse instructions as those are usually newer CPUs with more features.

Comment: @KamilKoczurek: yeah sure. But we're talking about the same processor. Is it the case, that for the same processor, there are more SSE instructions in 64-bit mode than in 32-bit mode?

Comment: Ok to avoid further discussion removing the note about more SSE instructions (but still more registers)